# Different scrolling speed Android

Tags: android, scroll

[image]I just wonder if it is possible to have different speeds on scrolling. Imagine we have two `ImageViews` in the page. while I'm scrolling first `ImageView` should move faster than the second `ImageView`. Is it possible and do you have any example for that ?! 
Cheers

As it shows on the image below, when starts scrolling imageView 1 move more than the imageView 2

Comment: By different scrolling speeds, do you mean 1) it should take longer of a scrolling action to happen in one image that it does in the other, or 2) the same gesture should result in more movement in one image that it does in the other.

Comment: Dear @DaleWilson, it's better to say the distance size. i mean when I scroll the page, Image 1 scroll as much as I scroll on the page but Image 2 move less. I'm making a pic for that on the PS. give me a min plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're looking for the PARALLAX effect:

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925114/android-live-wallpapers-parallax-scrolling-effect) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/160621/parallax-scrolling-image-background).

The former seems to be more Wallpaper oriented, but worth a deeper look.

The second is a link to CodeProject where there's a link to an open source game.

**[EDIT]**

Parallax effect is much used in games, especially the horizontal/vertical scrollers.

At least, when I was a kid (80s)

Comment: Cheers @Klaus66 :) I know , I'm working on an app that the UI designer gave me this UI and I have to make it ! thats why I was looking for this, Thanks a lot anyway :)